# How to use/show custom Picklists created in salesforce, in visualforce Pages to show possible values?

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, selectlist

I have some custom fields (Picklists) in Salesforce Instance, like **Languages__c** which contains some Languages names. 
I want to use it in a custom detail view of record, that is generated by using VIsualforce Page.

Here is a tag in visualforce  to design a picklist in visualforce page (I am not happy with its design as it does not looking nice as you can see)

[image]

and I have to give it **variable from Apex Controller** that is a list of names of some Languages, in value attribute.

Then this tag  is used to get all selected options by user, to save them in a variable and use that variable in Apex Controller to do further processing.
This is hectic.

Is there any way to use **custom Pick-list already created in Salesforce as custom field**, in Visualforce page to avoid my self from creating these fields using selectList etc.??

Or I must have to use selectList and Custom Controller variables to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could enable `State and Country/Territory Picklists` in your org. However it has consequences throughout your entire org in that it gets used across all of your existing data. You'll find it located under `DataManagement | State and Country/Territory Picklists`.

For your situation, `Global Picklists` would be ideal which is still in Beta. If in a Dev Org, you'd find it under `Create | Picklists`. If you can get into the Beta, that would be ideal

Comment: I try this. 
And please tell me whether it is possible to select multiple values from picklist just on clicking on them without holding "Ctrl" key together?

Comment: Only if you used the Global Picklists. Not for the State and Country picklists as you can only be from one location at a time.

Comment: It means we cant use Custom picklist created in Salesforce, in visualforce pages. We have to use apex:selectList and apex:selectOptions and Controller to make new list and use it??